# Problems with charset in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, iso-8859-1

I've some problems with special characters in PHP/MySQL (I don't know which one).
Then, I've data stored in a database,using php. I ensured before storing data to add this code:

```
  header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $link=mysqli_connect("host","user","","db") or die(mysqli_error($link));
  mysqli_query($link,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8';SET NAMES utf8");
```

I also ensured Apache uses the correct charset:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

In addition I also tried to add on every html page the `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
```

Further, I saved all my `php` and `html` files in `UTF-8` format.
I noticed that if I write a character like `ò` in a page and display that page it is correctly displayed. If I get a string query from a database containing `ò`, it doesn't display correctly, but if I change the code to:

```
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

the query retrieved from the DB is correctly displayed, a normal writing not.
So,the problem is on mysql charset? How could it be if I setted it with the previous instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your column where you store this date to utf8 also

here some codes you may use.

Change the character-set/collation (`database`):

> ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Change the character-set/collation (`table`):

> ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Change the character-set/collation (`columns`):

> ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: I tried those instructions and now works. Thanks echo_Me

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.php.net/mysqli_set_charset function instead of the mysqli_query() you are using now.

Comment: I also tried with `mysqli_set_charset` function, but nothing.